# what is the equivalent of theano.tensor.clip in pytorch?

Tags: theano, pytorch

I want to clip my tensor (not gradient) values to some range. Is there any function in pytorch like there is a function theano.tensor.clip() in theano?

Comment: If my answer has solved your issue, consider marking it as the correct answer, so this questions stays no longer unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are searching for is called `torch.clamp`. You can find the documentation [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.clamp)